# whlie loop never exiting even though variable updated

Tags: java, variables, android-asynctask, global

I have created a nested class that extends the AsyncTask to extract data from a database.
When the extraction is completed, it sets a global variable ("notificationsExtracted") to true, to say that the process is complete.

In the main calling code, I set up a while loop that waits for that global variable to become true, before using the data that was extracted, i.e.

```
while(!notificationsExtracted) {}
...now continue running other code...
```

On all phones except one, this works perfectly, but the one phone (Conexis x2 - Android 7.0) refuses to reflect the global variable being set to true.

When I do logging, it shows the flow of code instantiating the class, pulling the data works, setting the global variable to true, and then nothing.
On other phones, it does the above, but then continues running further code in the main program.

Briefly, I have the following in the calling program

```
public class FragmentMain extends Fragment {
  static private Boolean notificationsExtracted;
...
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_layout, parent, false);
    ...
    Log.i("notif", "1");
    notificationsExtracted = false;
    GetNotificationsNewMySQL getNotificationsNewMySQL = new GetNotificationsNewMySQL();
    getNotificationsNewMySQL.execute("");
    while (!notificationsExtracted) { };
    Log.i("notif", "2");
    ...
```

and then the nested class

```
private class GetNotificationsNewMySQL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                String q = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM training.app_notifications";
                Log.i("notif", "a");
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(q);
                Log.i("notif", "b");
                ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
                Log.i("notif", "c");
                while (rs.next()) {
                    notificationCount = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1).toString());
                }
                Log.i("notif", "d");
                notificationsExtracted = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("notif", "error extracting");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (notificationsExtracted)
                Log.i("notif", "true");
            else
                Log.i("notif", "false");
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        }
    }
```

Now on all phones except the one phone, it logs the following sequence of program flow

```
2019-11-15 11:18:40.338 1951-1951/com.example.pdcapp I/Notif: 1
2019-11-15 11:18:40.339 1951-1951/com.example.pdcapp I/Notif: 2
2019-11-15 11:18:40.438 1951-1951/com.example.pdcapp I/notif: 1
2019-11-15 11:18:40.512 1951-2025/com.example.pdcapp I/notif: a
2019-11-15 11:18:40.521 1951-2025/com.example.pdcapp I/notif: b
2019-11-15 11:18:40.521 1951-2025/com.example.pdcapp I/notif: c
2019-11-15 11:18:40.522 1951-2025/com.example.pdcapp I/notif: d
2019-11-15 11:18:40.522 1951-2025/com.example.pdcapp I/notif: true
2019-11-15 11:18:40.522 1951-1951/com.example.pdcapp I/notif: 2
```

except the one phone I get the following, with the result that the phone hangs, i.e. it never gets past the while loop:

```
2019-11-15 11:20:57.153 20089-20089/com.example.pdcapp I/Notif: 1
2019-11-15 11:20:57.154 20089-20089/com.example.pdcapp I/Notif: 2
2019-11-15 11:20:57.196 20089-20089/com.example.pdcapp I/notif: 1
2019-11-15 11:20:57.267 20089-20348/com.example.pdcapp I/notif: a
2019-11-15 11:20:57.274 20089-20348/com.example.pdcapp I/notif: b
2019-11-15 11:20:57.274 20089-20348/com.example.pdcapp I/notif: c
2019-11-15 11:20:57.274 20089-20348/com.example.pdcapp I/notif: d
2019-11-15 11:20:57.274 20089-20348/com.example.pdcapp I/notif: true
```

I would appreciate help on this please. As reference, I previously loooked for help on the following link https://androidforums.com/threads/while-loop-not-exiting.1315976/

Comment: The whole point of an async task is to execute blocking, long tasks in a different thread, to avoid blocking the UI thread and freezing your application. Having a while loop doing nothing except eating all the CPU and freezing the UI thread until the "background" task has finished makes it worse than not using an async task (and you're doing it in a non-thread-safe way, too). Read up on how to correctly use an async task, because the way you're doing it is a dead end.

Comment: The asyncTask takes <1s so I don't mind it stopping operation, although I do understand your point you make. However, it doesn't explain why the variable doesn't get updated.

Comment: Because it's not volatile, or atomic, or accessed from snchrnized blocks. So there's no visibility guarantee that the write done by one thread is visible by another thread.

Comment: But if it is a static global variable, why can a thread not update it?

Comment: A thread can. But the Java Memory Model doesn't guarantee that another thread will see the change, unless proper synchronization is used (volatile, atomic, synchronized). Multi-threading is a complex matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing goes against the principal of asynchronous execution. If you start an asynchTask, but then wait until it's finsished, it's not really async.
This is ok though, sometimes you simply need things to be done in a certain order but you can't do it on the main-thread.

I'm not exactly sure why your program doesn't work on a technical level, but I think I had a similar problem once. I believe that in Java, updating a variable from within one thread does not necessarily update the variable for all other threads too. Does Android Studio give you a warning on the while-loop?
I hope someone who has more experience with multi-threading in Java can say something about this.

However, the solution to your Problem is easy:
You want whatever Code after the while-loop to execute after the AsyncTask finished excecuting, so simply excecute that Code in the `onPostExcecute` method.

Comment: Variables defined outside of the scope of a thread are always updated in all threads in Java. If that had been the issue it would probably not have worked on the other phones. The `onPostExecute` might be a feasible solution though.

Comment: I tried onPostExecute as well by letting it set the variable to true instead of in asyncTask but then the app hung on all phones.

Comment: I understand about the threading needing to operate in parallel, and not letting it hold up my main thread, the thing is that I wanted to keep it separate from the main code, as well as the operation is very quick anyway (relatively), and so I don't mind waiting that second for it to complete

Comment: I didn't see your suggestion for the solution, I will see if I can do that, thank you. All I'm doing is updating a TextView anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please add logger after the lines where you obtain String q, ResultSet and ResultSetMetaData? Maybe it is stucking on these lines.

Comment: So I added extra logging as requested. The first output is from my phone (works as expected) the 2nd output is from the phone where it doesn't work
I/Notif: 1
I/Notif: 2
I/notif: 1
I/notif: a
/notif: b
I/notif: c
I/notif: d
I/notif: true
I/notif: 2

I/Notif: 1
I/Notif: 2
I/notif: 1
I/notif: a
I/notif: b
I/notif: c
I/notif: d
I/notif: true

I am not sure why 1 & 2 gets shown twice because I definitely initialise the variable before instantiating the AsyncTask class, so it shouldn't get to the "2"

Comment: Sorry, first time using StackOverflow, will add more info into the main question as requested

Comment: Apologies, I found the extra "1" & "2", it is from a different class relating to the notification cards I use, I had left some logging in there, that is why you will notice it has a capital "I/Notif". So it is unrelated to the program flow, I should actually just change the tag in the other class's logging.

Comment: The execution flow will go like this.

Comment: When `getNotificationsNewMySQL.execute("");` is called a new thread is opened and it enters doInBackGround() function. Meanwhile execution could pass to your `while(!notificationsExtracted)` check when notificationsExtracted is not set to true. You could wait until thread job is to finish for that specific phone.

Comment: The thread sets that variable to true, so if truly stuck in the thread, the global variable has been updated to true, and so in main thread it should then pass the while loop, even if the separate thread never finishes. This is shown in the logging that the variable does indeed get set to true, it just never "recognises" the state in the main thread.